Can some one help me how to make ffmpeg capturing with preview on PictureBox?
My system is Windows 10/11

I am making ffmpeg based video capturing software in VB6 with preview.
I could deal ffmpeg.exe only by command line.
Source is from Decklink card or Video file.
I can't use ffplay for preview, because I need the preview on my application window
unlike ffplay's floating window.
Most of it I need open source solution as my application is not for commercial use.
ffmpeg usual pipe can not be used, because I need the Preview first by process A.
When user decide to start Capture, that time only Process B will be executed.

Stage-1:
First I need to receive the source and show the preview on my application PictureBox/Form.
If its by ffmpeg, well, else some Directshow suggession needed.
I could do Stage-1 easily by VB6+Directshow, but how the same stream will be consumed by ffmpeg on Stage-2 ?
Stage-2:
ffmpeg command line should receive the same source (from above stream) and do the capturing on a file. (I can manage the commands for encoding and capturing on file)
Help needed:

How to render the preview on my application window with ffmpeg/ffplay ?
How to use the same video source if it is already used on Stage-1 by the preview process ?

Possibilities:
A)
I could manage it, if I get some Directshow Virtual Video/Audio Sink/Source filters.
But no where I could find Virtual Video/Audio Sink/Source filters
I may use the Virtual Sink filters on Directshow graph one with Preview.
ffmpeg will receive the same source from Virtual Source filter.
B)
By some means if I could create mkfifo in Windows, I could manage it.
But I doubt we can create fifo in Windows like Linux.
C)
If I could dump the Video/Audio stream on Memory and if ffmpeg receives that stream from memory, then it should work. But I don't know how to do it from ffmpeg command line.
Please help and suggest me the proper schema for this.
gaamaa
